# tensorflow IO dicom reader division by 2 issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, medical-imaging, tensorflow-io

i also encountered a strange division by 2 problem with my dicom files (I got them from https://wiki.cancerimagingarchive.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=52758026).  I am not sure how to upload files, but the following is how I read

```
image_bytes = tf.io.read_file(fname )
image = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(image_bytes, dtype=tf.uint16, on_error = 'lossy')
im = image.numpy () [0, :, :, 0].astype (np.uint16)
```

the values of the images are twice the correct value (so I have to divide everything by 2 to get the correct value).  I am using tf 2.3 and tfio 0.16.

BTW. I was able to read the tutorial chest x-ray image; but I am not sure if there's a division by 2 issue as well, since I don't know what the correct values should be.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anything DICOM related, I can recommend using `pydicom`.
Reading the image and accessing `pixel_array` looks fine to me.

Comment: yes, pydicom and pixel_array indeed work very well, and gives the correct pixel value. The issue here is to use tensorflow io to directly work with dcm files and convert to a tf tensor, without going through the numpy array step.

Comment: What happens if you substitute your last line with `im = np.squeeze(image.numpy())`? How do you figure out that you have to divide by 2? Did you try to load the same image with `pydicom` and `tfio` and compared the resulting image arrays?